# How to get ripgrep to tell me which expressions from a list have no matches on the filesystem

Tags: grep, ag, ripgrep

For instance, say I have the list of strings that I want to search for:

```
alfa bravo charlie delta nebuchadnezzar bartholomew
```

and in my repo there are files that contain `alfa`, `bravo`, `charlie` and `delta`, but there are **no** files that contain `nebuchadnezzar` and **no** files that contain `bartholomew`.  Then I want the answer to be:

```
nebuchadnezzar bartholomew
```

As you might guess, I'm searching for deprecated things.  I ended up using the following Ruby code workaround as I couldn't figure a solution after trying `man rg`.

```
%w[alfa bravo charlie delta nebuchadnezzar bartholomew].each do |word|
  command = 'rg ' + word
  if `#{command}` == ''  # execute the command, see if ripgrep found nothing
    puts word
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the exit code of `rg` when no match is found in a simple shell loop construct. From the [docs](https://www.mankier.com/1/rg), it seems it returns a code 1 when no match is found for the regex and no errors are seen. Adopting it

```sh
for word in alfa bravo charlie delta nebuchadnezzar bartholomew; do
    rg "$word" >/dev/null 2>&1
    [ "$?" -eq 1 ] && printf '%s\n' "no match for $word"
done
```

Comment: Hm, could also use `--quiet`, found that when searching the docs for "exit code".  The docs say:  --quiet ... Do not print anything to stdout. If a match is found in a file, then ripgrep will stop searching. This is useful when ripgrep is used only for its exit code (which will be an error if no matches are found).